# Delete graphite events via API

Tags: curl, graphite

I am using graphite and grafana and I need to create some events in graphite.

I am currently doing it with curl and it works well:

```
 curl -X POST http://graphite/events/ -d '{"what": "did_stuff", "tags" : "fun,times"}'
```

However, I did not find how to delete all events or a concrete event.

I tried DELETE requests to /events or delete to /events/id but a 405 http code is returned.

Does anyone knows how to delete events from the API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the Graphite events [source code](https://github.com/graphite-project/graphite-web/tree/master/webapp/graphite/events) and I don't see a delete API. You can delete events via the Django Admin web UI (at http://my.graph.ite/admin/events/event) so you should be able to use the Django admin APIs to delete events programatically.

FWIW here are the content of the form when I delete multiple events via the Django web UI:

```
_selected_action    52
_selected_action    51
_selected_action    50
_selected_action    49
_selected_action    48
action     delete_selected
csrfmiddlewaretoken  REDACTED
index       0
select_across       0
Source
csrfmiddlewaretoken=REDACTED&action=delete_selected&select_across=0&index=0&_selected_action
=52&_selected_action=51&_selected_action=50&_selected_action=49&_selected_action=48
```

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can also modify the Graphite DB directly.

```
Delete all records.
# sqlite3 /opt/graphite/storage/graphite.db
sqlite> DELETE FROM events_event;
sqlite> 

Delete record by ID.
# sqlite3 /opt/graphite/storage/graphite.db
sqlite> SELECT * FROM events_event;
1|2016-02-26 13:55:50|STARTING REGION DEPLOYMENT 1.0.0||deployment

sqlite> DELETE FROM events_event WHERE id=1;
```

Comment: The django admin is so messed up to create user for it... This one is still a valid solution :)